# Is it possible to initialize Angular.js for DOM element instead of for whole document?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making relatively complex jQuery UI plugin and I'm thinking about using Angular to simplify development.

But as I know, Angular initializes itself using whole document.

Is it possible, to initialize Angular.js and make it compile templates in bounds of chosen DOM element?

Comment: Angular is probably not the best choice for a plugin unless it's an entirely for your own project, or for use by people already using Angular. You might look at lighterweight solutions with a smaller scope, like RivetsJS or KnockoutJS.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think Backbone.js also can be added to that list.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder BTW, why you think, that Angular is poor choice for such task?

Comment: Sure, and a dozen others, such a React or even single-way templating like Handlebars. Re why Angular seems like a poor choice: Angular is an *application framework*, and you're not using it for an application, but rather a jQuery UI plugin. Some of these others are much more targeted and don't try to take over the whole app.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Do you now some examples of relatively popular jQuery plugins that uses such libraries as Backbone, Knockout, etc?

Comment: No, I think plugins _in general_ try to avoid dependencies of any kind.

Answer (score 2):

The [`ng-app` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) determines the root element of the Angular "application." I think anything outside the tree rooted in that element is left alone.

Comment: What if somebody specify another `ng-app` dicrective?

Comment: @GillBates: Then you're probably stuffed. :-) You can probably modularize things enough that, with adequate documentation, the plugin would be compatible with Angular and non-Angular pages (giving the user a model if they already use Angular), but it seems fairly complex.

Comment: @GillBates Then you'll do [manual initialization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization). (Or rather "should do")

Comment: @Yoshi: Seems like you're probably better placed to answer this than I am.

Comment: I just looked at this by coincidence ;). And what you wrote is actually correct (as far as my knowledge goes). The only extra bit, is that *one could* opt for manual initialization if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible
Angular starts compilation where it gets the ng-app attributes.

Use ng-app attribute on your dom where you want angular to be used rather than inside html or body.

Ex

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!--html to be compiled by angularjs-->
    <div ng-app="yourAngularApp">
    </div>
 <!--html code outside of angular access-->
  <div>This element will not be compiled by angularjs</div>
  </body>
</html>
```